# How to zoom in on cursor point in Mandelbrot Set?

Tags: c++, opengl, zooming, translation

I'm currently trying to implement a zoom feature for the Mandelbrot Set code I've been working on. The idea is to zoom in/out where I left/right click. So far whenever I click the screen, the fractal is indeed zoomed in. The issue is that the fractal is rendered not at the origin-- in other words, it's not zoomed in on the point I want. I was hoping through here I can get both a code review and conceptual understanding of how to zoom in on a point in general.

Here's how I transformed the pixel coordinate before I used escape algorithm:

MandelBrot.Frag

```
vec2 normalizedFragPos = (gl_FragCoord.xy/windowSize); //normalize fragment position

dvec2 scaledFragPos = normalizedFragPos*aspectRatio;

scaledFragPos -= aspectRatio/2; //Render the fractal at center of window

scaledFragPos /= scale; //Factor to zoom in or out coordinates.

scaledFragPos -= translation; //Translate coordinate
//Escape Algorithm Below
```

On my left-click handle, I thought I should convert the cursor position to the same coordinate range as the Mandelbrot Range. So I basically did the same thing I did in the fragment shader:

Window.cpp

```
float x_coord{ float(GET_X_LPARAM(informaton_long))/size.x }; // normalized mouse x-coordinate
float y_coord{ float(GET_Y_LPARAM(informaton_long))/size.y }; // normalized mouse y-coordinate

x_coord *= aspectRatio[0]; //move point based of relative position to length of window.
y_coord *= aspectRatio[1]; //move point based of relative position to width of window.
x_coord /= scale; //Scale point to match previous zoom factor
y_coord /= scale; //Scale point to match previous zoom factor
translation[0] = x_coord;
translation[1] = y_coord;
//increment scale
scale += .15f;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets apply some algebra. Your shader does the following transformation:

```
mandelbrotCoord = aspectRatio * (gl_FragCoord / windowSize - 0.5) / scale - translation
```

When we zoom in on `mouseCoord`, we want to change the `scale` and adjust the `translation` such that the `madelbrotCoord` under the mouse stays the same. To do that we first calculate the `mandelbrotCoord` under the mouse using the old scale:

```
mandelbrotCoord = aspectRatio * (mouseCoord / windowSize - 0.5) / scale - translation
```

Then change the scale (which should be changed exponentially BTW):

```
scale *= 1.1;
```

Then solve for the new translation:

```
translation = aspectRatio * (mouseCoord / windowSize - 0.5) / scale - mandelbrotCoord
```

Also notice that your system probably reports the mouse coordinate with the `y` coordinate increasing downwards, whereas OpenGL has its window `y` coordinate increasing upwards (unless you override it with `glClipControl`). Therefore you're likely to need to flip the `y` coordinate of the `mouseCoord` too.

```
mouseCoord[1] = windowSize[1] - mouseCoord[1];
```

For best result I would also adjust the mouse coordinates to be in the middle of the pixel (+0.5, +0.5).

Putting it all together:

```
float mouseCoord[] = {
    GET_X_LPARAM(informaton_long) + 0.5,
    GET_Y_LPARAM(informaton_long) + 0.5
};
mouseCoord[1] = size[1] - mouseCoord[1];

float anchor[] = {
    aspectRatio[0] * (mouseCoord[0] / size[0] - 0.5) / scale - translation[0],
    aspectRatio[1] * (mouseCoord[1] / size[1] - 0.5) / scale - translation[1]
};

scale *= 1.1;

translation[0] = aspectRatio[0] * (mouseCoord[0] / size[0] - 0.5) / scale - anchor[0];
translation[1] = aspectRatio[1] * (mouseCoord[1] / size[1] - 0.5) / scale - anchor[1];
```

Note: some of the math above might be canceled away. However, if you want to implement a proper pan&zoom functionality (when you can zoom with the mouse wheel while you are panning) then you'll need to store the initial `mandelbrotCoord` of where the panning started, and then reuse it on subsequent motion and wheel events till the mouse is released. Surprisingly large amount of image viewers get this part wrong!

Comment: Yo dude, thanks so much for explaining it perfectly! Though I understood that zoom point would remain the same in both the new and old scale, I couldn't piece together how I could use the mouse coordinate to get the new translation. I simply considered the mandelbrot coordinate that the mouse points too as the translation value. Thanks again, I've been scratching my head for 3 days on this smh lol!